# Specflow step is not bound even though the underlying step definitions have been implemented

Tags: automated-testing, c#, bdd, specflow

[image]

Hello, the step has not been bound (hence, colour purple), even though the underlying step defintions have been implemented.

In the screen shot, I clicked on "Ok". V/Studio takes me to the screen in the next screen shot.

[image]

I have tried a few things:

1. Commented out any other scenarios that may have a similar step
2. Clicked on the "Save All" button in order to save any changes.
3. I have also rebuilt the solution. The error shown in the screen shot has been fixed. So, there are no outstanding errors in the project.

Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does it work when you execute the scenarios?

Comment: No, I am unable to execute the scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio caches the step bindings, and sometimes this cache becomes out of sync with your code. The fix is a bit obtuse, but simple. Close all Visual Studio windows and delete files in your temp directory matching `stepmap`

1. Close all Visual Studio windows
2. Open File Explorer
3. Click on the location bar showing the current directory. It should turn into an editable text field and highlight the folder path
4. Type `%TEMP%` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to navigate to your temp directory
5. Type `stepmap` in the search file text box towards the upper right corner of File Explorer
6. Delete all files that show up in the file search

Or open a Windows command prompt and type:

```
del %TEMP%\*stepmap*
```

Comment: This Fixed The Issue.. Arigato !

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods with the same Then expression in your StudentStepDefinition.cs file:

```
    [Then(@"A New Student Record Amoo Should Be Created")]
```

Each expression needs its own unique expression to be able to bind and run it.

So you need to remove one.

Comment: I have commented the other statement out. But, I still get the error.

Comment: That is due to your other question? Not regeneration the feature.cs files?